# Double integral - transformation

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

I'm trying to calculate $$\iint_{\Omega } e^{(x+y^2)^{3/2}} \,\mathrm{d}A,$$ where $$\Omega =\{x,y>0 : x+y\leq 2\}. $$ 
Not sure where to go with it. I need to find a transformation and then calculate the integral. Any pointers?

Comment: Are you sure the question had $x+y^2$ in the exponent and not $x^2+y^2$?

Comment: Yeah it's defininitely $x+y^2$.

Comment: Okay, can you also verify that the region of integration is correct?

Comment: (The reason I am asking these questions is because the integral you posted appears to have no closed form expression.)

Comment: I've tried with this coordinate change, but it doesn't seems easy either $\begin{cases}
  x=t^2-s^2\\
  y=s
\end{cases}$

Answer (score 1):

With the substitution
\begin{align*}
x &= (r\cos\theta)^2 \\
y &= r\sin\theta 
\end{align*}
we find
\begin{align*}
\iint_{\Omega } e^{(x+y^2)^{3/2}} \,d A
&= \int_0^{\pi/2}\int_0^{R(\theta)} 2 e^{r^3}r^2\cos\theta \,dr\,d\theta \\
&= \frac{2}{3} \int_0^{\pi/2}(e^{R(\theta)^3}-1)\cos\theta\,d\theta,
\end{align*}
where
$$R(\theta) = \frac{-\sin\theta+\sqrt{8-7\sin^2\theta}}{2\cos^2\theta}.$$
($R(\theta)$ is found by solving $x(r,\theta)+y(r,\theta) = 2$ for $r$.)
Letting $\sin\theta = t$ we find
\begin{align*}
\iint_{\Omega } e^{(x+y^2)^{3/2}} \,\mathrm{d}A
&= \frac{2}{3} \int_0^1 \left(\exp\left[\left(\frac{-t+\sqrt{8-7t^2}}{2(1-t^2)}\right)^3\right] -1\right)dt \\
&= -\frac 2 3 + \frac{2}{3} \int_0^1 \exp\left(\frac{64}{(t+\sqrt{8-7t^2})^3}\right) dt.
\end{align*}
The final one-dimensional integral may be found numerically.

Comment: That integral behaves badly when nearing $t=1$. How do you calculate that?

Comment: @syockit: I appreciate your close reading. One can think of this as an improper integral or note that $$\frac{-t+\sqrt{8-7t^2}}{2(1-t^2)} = \frac{4}{t+\sqrt{8-7t^2}},$$ which is well behaved on $[0,1]$.

Comment: Neat, it escaped my mind that you could the surd removal trick on the numerator. I always thought that it was only applicable for the denominator, and gave up.